# Eclipse debugger not working with Android appWidget application?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have an appWidget project I've been working on and noticed the Eclipse debugger does not seem to be working.  I thought it might be borked, so I opened up another Android project and set a breakpoint and it worked fine.  In my appWidget application however, the debugger will not work no matter where I set the breakpoint.  I can set the breakpoint right on a Log statement, see the message print, but there is no interruption of execution.

I read something about having to install the 'Android sources' but it seems to me that if the debugger was missing something, it wouldn't work at all.  The only clue I have is Logcat is printing "Debugger has detached" which offers little help. Other posts have suggested two Eclipse processes running (`ps -ef` shows only one), restarting adb (I've done `adb kill-server; adb start-server`) or that the process crashed, which Logcat does not show:

```
  5486         AndroidRuntime  D  
  5486         AndroidRuntime  D  >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
  5486         AndroidRuntime  I  Heap size: -Xmx48m
  5486         AndroidRuntime  D  CheckJNI is OFF
  5486               dalvikvm  D  creating instr width table
  5486         AndroidRuntime  D  Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
  5486         AndroidRuntime  D  Shutting down VM
  5486               dalvikvm  D  GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 70% free 307K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+0ms
  5486               dalvikvm  D  Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
  5486         AndroidRuntime  I  NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #1' failed
```

That's all Logcat says when I launch the application in debug mode. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think it's because app widget is just a broadcast receiver hosted by the home screen process

Comment: It must be. I've tried two other applications and the Debugger works as expected so Eclipse must be OK. I guess we're just supposed to use Logcat for debugging these types of things. :/